# Java - ProcessBuilder hanging while executing a shell script that returns nothing

Tags: java

I know there are plenty of questions answered about processbuilder hanging while executing a command. I went through most of the answers, but nothing works for me so I am either missing something obvious or something else is wrong in my code. So here goes.

I have a java method that does this

```
final File tmp = File.createTempFile("out", null);
System.out.println("Tmp File path: "+tmp.getAbsolutePath());
tmp.deleteOnExit();
System.out.println("Executing script: "+ app + " " + report + " " + oldFileName + " " + newFileName);
ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(app, report, oldFileName, newFileName).redirectErrorStream(true).redirectOutput(tmp);
procBuilder.redirectError(tmp);
Process proc = procBuilder.start();
// throw exception if the process fails
try {
    proc.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
int changes = proc.exitValue();
if (changes != 0) {
    throw new FileCompareException("File Comparison found changes: " + newFileName);
    }
```

The command resolves to call a shell script like this

src/main/resources/scripts/./vimdiff.sh src/main/resources/auth/report/report.html src/main/resources/tests/goldenFile/golden_online src/main/resources/genFile/file_20170715234458224.log

The shell script itself is calling vimdiff to diff between two files and create an output.

```
VAR="vimdiff -c TOhtml -c 'w $1 | qall!' $2 $3 &> /dev/null"
eval $VAR
```

Now when I run the program from eclipse, it just hangs at proc.waitfor method. But when I copy the out of the generated command and run it from the command line it runs without any issues.

In the shell script, I am directing any output to /dev/null, so no output stream issue should arise. However, I am directing the output to a tmp file using redirectErrorStream(true).redirectOutput(tmp) in my code anyway. So I am at a loss. Why is my program hanging?

Comment: This [link](http://java-monitor.com/forum/showthread.php?t=4067) explains a deadlock case nicely: check and see if it may work for your case.`When your external process produces output, that is written into the buffer. Your code is expected to read from that buffer. If you do not the data from that buffer, it will eventually block`

Comment: But this is exactly what I am doing. I am routing the error stream and output stream to an temp file. I dont see anything added to the tmp file (because the script does not return anything), but the script still hangs when I run the java program.